# Is it safe to get a bean from spring context using passed arguments?

Tags: java, spring, command-line

For example:
passing as argument the following:

```
myarg=abc

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (ctx.containsBean(args[0].split("=")[1])) {
        Bean b= ctx.getBean(args[0].split("=")[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by safe?

Comment: If you trust the one that starts your program, it is safe. If not, then not.

Comment: I mean 'good' or 'normal practice'. I would like to know if someone knows some better alternative

Comment: By the way, there is the [0] missing in the second call to args. So do it once and correct before the if.

Comment: I would say it's not the normal practice, but if you have to, because of your requirements, do it.

Comment: My requirements are: to generate different kind of pages depending on the arguments I pass. So for example I launch the application passing generation=genthis and it wil generate pages of kind 'genthis'

Comment: Do you have some alternative to suggest?